# Import particular contact details from addressbook in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, addressbookui

In my app I import a contact details using addressbookui.In case of email or mobile number empty my app getting crashed.

Comment: Are you selecting contact from address-book or fetching whole address-book to your app?

Comment: select a single contact from addressbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For email try this:

```
 ABMutableMultiValueRef eMail  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);

    if(ABMultiValueGetCount(eMail) > 0) 
 {
      NSString *personEmail =  (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(eMail, 0);
  }
```

Comment: For mobile number :                            'ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneno  = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    
if(ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneno) > 0) 
  {
        NSString *pNo =  (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneno, 0);
      
 }'